# Y-axis changes with bandwidth in geom_density in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

As far as I understand it, the area under a density curve should always be equal to 1. This does not seem to be the case in R.

My code looks like this:

```
p <- ggplot() +
  geom_density(data = data_plot, aes_string(x = "value", color = group_by),
               position = "identity", size = 0.5, na.rm = TRUE) +
  labs(x = data_plot$unit[data_plot[, group_by] == group_member[1]], y = "density") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = color) +
        theme_own()
plot(p)
```

When I change the `geom_density` input into

```
geom_density(data = data_plot, aes_string(x = "Wert", color = group_by),
               position = "identity", size = 0.5, na.rm = TRUE, bw = bandwidth)
```

I get different values on the y-axis.

No manual bw:

[image: No manual bw]

Bw = 0.01:

[image: Bw = 0.01]

Bw = 0.00001:

[image: Bw = 0.00001]

Am I interpreting something wrong? I did expect the range of the y-axis to get bigger with a rising bandwith (since many values are at 67 and 100), but shouldn't the curves be lower? For example in the last plot the area is around 30(x-axis)*100(y-axis)=3'000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that the total area under a probability density curve should be always 1. However, this restriction would still allow the density values on the y-axis to go beyond 1, since you will have to multiply the height of the density area you are interested in with the width of the corresponding area (which is usually done by solving integrals)

Consider, for example, a uniform distribution ranging from 0 to 0.1. Here, the constant density value would be 10, since 0.1 * 10 = 1.

```
# example: the shorter the interval between min and max, the larger the 
# the density value becomes
  curve(dunif(x = x, min = 0, max = 0.1), from = 0, to = 0.1)
```

[image: PDF of uniform distribution from 0 to 1]

With the bandwidth argument in your code, you are essentially making the intervals of interest smaller and smaller, which results in higher and higher density values.

Comment: "With the bandwidth argument in your code, you are essentially making the intervals of interest smaller and smaller, which results in higher and higher density values." You are right, this is why I was expecting getting a bigger range with rising bandwith. So I do understand that the y axis can go beyond 1. 
But if you look at my last plot, the area is far bigger than 1 (I would estimate it to be around 3'000). As far as I see it, in this plot the area really is bigger than 1. Or would you interpret that plot differently?

Comment: First thing to note: You mentioned in your question that  most values are at 67. Strictly speaking, this is not continuous, but discrete. Density functions like probability density functions assume continuous data. With regards to interpretation of area, try seeing the density function as a a smoothed histogram with the probability on the y axis and increasing number of breaks.                                                                                       
 x <- rnorm(10000)
hist(x, breaks = 1000, probability = TRUE)

Comment: You will see that with increased number of breaks, the area will also start to look like it is above 1. Generally speaking, I would avoid giving too much focus on the y axis in density plots (especially when the data are not continuous) and rather on the proportion of density of different areas compared with each other (which is unaffected by the scale)